# 1989 mazda 323 hatchback

Tags: coolant, temperature, gauges

I have a 1989 Mazda 323 hatchback. Does not get hot. A friend of mine hooked up a new stereo for me but my temperature gauge stopped working. I need to know where to look to plug it back in or change a fuse. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!